# customize ordered list-style

Tags: css, html-lists

Hey there I am trying to modify the ol list style like in that picture another website is allready dooing.
[image]

But with another CSS Image instead of the circle like the form (without text) in that picture
[image]

I tried the following code to rebuild what the other website is dooing, but I have no idea how to change the blue circle into a that green symbol. Can you help me?

```css
 .blog-blau-liste {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.8em 0px 0px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    counter-reset: big-numba;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

.blog-blau-liste-item {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0.8em 0px 0px 1.9em;
    list-style: outside none none;
}

.blog-blau-liste-item::before {
    content: counter(big-numba, decimal);
    counter-increment: big-numba;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    font-size: 19px;
    left: -1.9em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #009DD9 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <ol class="blog-blau-liste">
 <li class="blog-blau-liste-item">Punkt Nummer 1</li>
 <li class="blog-blau-liste-item">Punkt Nummer 2</li>
 <li class="blog-blau-liste-item">Punkt Nummer 3</li></ol>
```

Is there a way to do so and build this green logo (only this kind of circle without text and white line) with css?

I found this code but it is not rounded and I dont know how to integrate that.

```css
#burst-8 {
    background: red;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(20deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(20eg);
}
#burst-8:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(135deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="burst-8">1</div>
```

Comment: Oh you want just the shape? Would there be numbers in it too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using `::after` and `::before` pseudo elements to recreate shape

This approach combines both methods I wrote earlier (see old answers below). The only limitation is that you can only have **8 sides**, otherwise you'd need to create extra HTML elements inside each `li`. This is the cleanest approach IMHO:

```css
.vegan-list {
    list-style: none;
    counter-reset: vegan-list-number;
}

.vegan-list li { position: relative; margin-bottom: 20px;}

.vegan-list li::before, .vegan-list li::after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
}

.vegan-list li::before {
  content: counter(vegan-list-number, decimal);
  counter-increment: vegan-list-number;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.vegan-list li::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<ol class="vegan-list">
  <li>Punkt Nummer 1</li>
  <li>Punkt Nummer 2</li>
  <li>Punkt Nummer 3</li>
</ol>
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/Lda7hwkj/

As you can see, the transform is applied to the `::after` element so that the number is not affected. Adding `z-index: -1` makes sure that `::after` does not overlap `::before`.

---

**Original Answer:**

You can apply the image as a background to each `li`'s `::before` pseduo element:

```css
.vegan-list {
    list-style: none;
}

.vegan-list li::before {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWoRZ.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="vegan-list">
  <li>Punkt Nummer 1</li>
  <li>Punkt Nummer 2</li>
  <li>Punkt Nummer 3</li>
</ol>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/ffyrhu7o/

---

**Edit:** If you wanted to recreate that shape with pure CSS, you can use `border-radius` to have the edges rounded/smooth:

```css
body {margin:3em;}

.burst {
  background: green;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #FFF;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.burst::before, .burst::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  transform: rotate(27deg);
}

.burst::after {
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="burst">1</div>
```

play with it - jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/r3wtjemr/

Comment: Great that looks good, thanks a lot! But how can I do this css symbol now for the list, that it looks like your first solution?

Comment: Thank you so much! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You could just add this png image before each of your sentences. 
It won't cost a lot to your page and will be a lot of simpler.
You will be able to customize it as you wish. 
If you want to make it dynamic you can use :

- a class attribute + Jquery (with [before](http://api.jquery.com/before/) for example)
- [ul list-style-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp)
- or even with css before as you did > see [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668577/using-before-css-pseudo-element-to-add-image-to-modal)

Answer (score 0):

```
ol{ 
    list-style-image: url("YourImage.png") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    .vegan-list {
        list-style: none;
      counter-reset: section;
    }

    .vegan-list li::before {
       counter-increment: section;
    content: counter(section);
      display:inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWoRZ.png") no-repeat center;
      background-size: contain;
       line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-large;
    color: brown;
    }
```

```html
    <ol class="vegan-list">
      <li>Punkt Nummer 1</li>
      <li>Punkt Nummer 2</li>
      <li>Punkt Nummer 3</li>
    </ol>
```