# How to insert an unselectable quotation mark (usually at the beginning) into a page?

Tags: html, css, quotes, double-quotes

I saw this many times but I just don't get how to insert this into a page. It is usually a double quotation mark at the beginning and is unselectable. Here is what I'm talking about:

> [image]

How can I insert this into a page?

Comment: P.S. I'm sorry if the question is vague. I don't know how to frame it better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using :before CSS pseudo element to add image to modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668577/using-before-css-pseudo-element-to-add-image-to-modal) (substitute `:after` with `:before`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can make it selectable, but easier (IMAO) for coding, with two paragraphs, one with “, second with text:

```html
<div>
  <p style="padding-left: 10px; width: 50px; height: 100%; font-size: 50px; float: left; color: gray; margin-top: 15px;"><i>"</i></p>
  <p style="width: calc(100% - 60px); float: right;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: You can make " unselectable, if you want it, with css `user-select: none;`:

```html
<div>
  <p style="user-select: none; padding-left: 10px; width: 50px; height: 100%; font-size: 50px; float: left; color: gray; margin-top: 15px;"><i>"</i></p>
  <p style="width: calc(100% - 60px); float: right;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```